How can I update the Session info on Every Refresh?
I have an admin portal where the admin can edit other users' names. However, if a user is already logged in with the name "John" and their name is updated to "Michael," the change doesn't reflect properly in NextAuth session.

In nextauth route on auth options route ,try adding following callbacks, here for each page/api call from server, refresh token will updated with latest user name from db.
const authOptions = {
//other configurations
callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.name = token.name;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: JWT; user: User }) {
      if (token && token.email) {
        // add your function instead of following
        const user = await getUserForLogin(token.email);
        //make sure to handle negative scenarios
        token.name = user.name;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },


}

